# Fabricjs SVG borders overflow

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm loading custom SVG to canvas with fabricjs, but it looks little bit weird, I don't understand why boarders is bigger than actual shape?

Here is working  example:
`jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/526wC/14/

How I can load SVG with exact size? Like this:

[image]

Or is there any way to resize svg to fit current entire drawing?

Comment: I believe it's written directly into the SVG itself. You may need to compile a more compact version.

Comment: Any advice to do automatically any command line tool or something

Comment: Don't know vectors too well. There might be a way to do it at runtime before fabric actually draws the object. Will look into it but I don't think I'd be the best for it :(